# How to delete secret from replicated region first and then primary region

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have a secret stored in us-east-1 and us-west-1, in this the primary region is us-east-1
If i hit any api call the secret gets created in primary region and gets replicated to other region. But when i hit the api to delete the secret on primary, it is saying you can't delete as it is already there in us-west-1
So how to delete the replicated region first and then primary region
Answer in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete each replica secret from a Region by removing the replica secret from the primary secret, and then deleting it.

You cannot delete a primary secret if a replica secret exists for it.

To know more about the Node.js please visit to : https://www.softsuave.com/blog/impact-of-nodejs-developers-in-real-time-web-app-development/

Comment: I have to delete the secrets from the replicated regions and then from the primary regions right?

Comment: I know i cannot delete the secret if a replica does exist for it, but how exactly i need to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a secret in one region (`us-west-2`) and you replicated the secret to another region (`us-east-2`). When you try to delete the original secret (`us-west-2`), you'll notice an error like this:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DeleteSecret operation: You can't delete secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:mysecretarn that still has replica regions [us-east-2].
```

You'll need to run a command like `aws --region=us-east-2 secretsmanager stop-replication-to-replica --secret-id <mysecretarn>` first. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/stop-replication-to-replica.html)

Then you can delete any secrets like `aws secretsmanager delete-secret --secret-id arn:mysecretarn`. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/delete-secret.html)